# How to check if session is set in JQuery warning: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

My website has login system and when the link with the id `show` is clicked, I want it to **display login window** if **session is not set**. And when **session is set** (when logged in), I want the `show` link to **show a drop down menu.**

How do I achieve this via PHP or JQuery or by using both? Also, I don't want to redirect or refresh the page.

below is the code that I've written and it does not work:

**index.php**

```
<a href="" id = "show">SHOW</a>

//this is hidden
<div id="dropdown">
    <a href="one.php">one</a>
    <a href="two.php">two</a>
</div>

//this is hidden
<div id="loginWindow">
    <p>please login</p>
    ....code
</div>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include_once('database.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        echo    '<script>',
                '$(function(){ afterLoginIcon(); })',
                '</script>';

    }
    if (!(isset($_SESSION['username']))){
        echo    '<script>',
                '$(function(){ showpopup(); })',
                '</script>';

    }
    else {echo "something went wrong"; return false;}


    ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

**script.js**

```
$('#show').click(function (e) {
    $.post( "loginIcon.php" );
    return false; //to prevent refreshing the page
});

function showpopup()
{
     $("#loginWindow").fadeIn();
     $("#loginWindow").css({"visibility":"visible","display":"block"});
}

function afterLoginIcon() {
    $("#dropdown").show();
}
```

**EDIT**: I have changed `$.post( "loginIcon.php" );` to `$('#show').load( 'loginIcon.php' );` and it works, however, in console, I get warning that says **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.**

Comment: `and it does not work` - obviously it doesn't work, you wouldn't be asking a question if it worked. More to the point is, in what way does it not work. Do you get errors on the server? Errors in the browser console? What is the expected output? What do you get instead ... the more details you provide the better

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't get any errors. It does not do anything as if I didn't even click the `show` button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning javascript code from the php script, you can just return a string "1" if user is logged in or "0" if user is not

```
$('#show').click(function (e) {
    $.post("login.php", function(data) {
       if(data == "1"){
          afterLoginIcon()
          // user is logged in and menu should show
       } else if(data == "0"){
          // user not logged in and form should show
          showPopup();
       }
    });
});
```

The reason why the functions are not being called is because you were returning a string as the response from the php script and strings will not be executed as javascript statements

The php script will then look like this

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include_once('database.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      echo '1';
    } else {
      echo '0';
    }


    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand `loginIcon.php` in `$.post()`. don't I need to use **login.php**? and how does `data == "1"` work?

Comment: sorry that was a mistake, it should be `login.php`. Whatever you `echo` from the `login.php` script can be accessed with the data variable